# What strategy should one use to solve this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, gauss-law

Is it possible to solve this using Gauss law choosing a cylinder around one of the plates or should I something else?

[image]

Comment: Since this seems like a homework question, I will just say that conceptually, yes you can solve for the electric field in this example using a cylinder as the Guassian surface. Think about why it's helpful that $d<< 2a$.

Comment: @Anonymousphysicist Thanks for the reply. This is a question from an old exam. The answer to this question is $$ C = \frac{\epsilon_0 \epsilon_r \pi a^2}{d} $$. I assume this is helpfull since I can now assume uniform field and no field leaking outisde the plates? And can hence use a simpler formula like $$ C = \frac{\epsilon S}{d} $$ where S is the surface area of the plates?

Comment: Yeah, if $d<<2a$, then you can neglect the electric field at the edges, where the electric field lines are not straight.

Comment: Thanks for the help!